# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python

I'm new to Python but a seasoned vet in other languages but why does data.dtype throw the error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'` and how can I get the dtype value?

From [this](http://samcarcagno.altervista.org/blog/basic-sound-processing-python/) blog it looks like I should be able to just do `data.dtype`

Code

```
import pyaudio
import sys
import numpy
import scipy.io.wavfile

# Ensures that a file is passed in as an argument
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)

file = sys.argv[1];

# Read the file
data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(file)
rate = data[0]
print data
print "rate = ", rate
print data[1]
print "format = ", data.dtype
```

Output

```
(44100, array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]], dtype=int16))
rate =  44100
[[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
format = 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 31, in <module>
    print "format = ", data.dtype
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Comment: because `data` is a tuple and `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'`. What is unclear about it?

Comment: `scipy.io.wavfile.read` returns a tuple, which doesn't have a `dtype` attribute. Oh, and you don't need to end every statement with a semicolon.

Comment: Updated question to be more clear

Comment: There _is_ no `dtype` for that object.

Comment: How is that any clearer? What's the color of my dog if I don't have a dog?

Comment: Did you mean `data[1].dtype`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that works. Thanks for pointing it out. Can you post it as an answer so I can give you the credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog where you got this code has a difference: it unpacks the result of the `scipy.io.wavfile.read()` call into two variables, while your code does not.

```
sampFreq, snd = wavfile.read('440_sine.wav')
```

That means `snd` has a `dtype`. In your code, you have this:

```
data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(file)
```

You then have to access the second element of the tuple you didn't unpack:

```
          vvv
print data[1]
print "format = ", data[1].dtype
                       ^^^
```